# Getting a value from database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Afternoon all!

So, I'm trying to get a value from my database and this is my sample code:

> MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from tbluser where
>   userName ='" + txtUser.Text + "' and userPass ='" + txtPass.Text +
>   "'", con);
>
> ```
>                 con.Open();
>                 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>                 int count = 0;
>
>                 while (reader.Read())
>                 {
>                     count = count + 1;
>                 }
>
>                 if (count == 1)
>                 {
>
>
>                         if (reader.HasRows) 
>                         {
>                             while (reader.Read()) 
>                             {
>                                 lblID.Text = reader(0);
>                             }
>                          }
>
>
>
>                     MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged in!");
>
>                     homeMain homeMain = new homeMain();
>
>                     homeMain.Passvalue = txtUser.Text;
>                     homeMain.Passvalue = lblID.Text;
>                     homeMain.Show();
>                     this.Hide();
>
>
>
>                 }
> ```

What the code is trying to achieve is, when I press LOG-IN, it searches the database equal to the txtUser and then displays the id on the lbl.Text. I got squiggly lines under reader(0). What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Use [] to access an item of an array

Comment: It's `reader[0]` not `()`

Comment: I tried that too already sir, but I got this error instead:
'hotelSys.logIn.reader' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternatively: `lblID.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();`

Comment: That won't work. `reader[0]` will be an object, while `.Text` expects a string

Comment: I tried that too and yes, it didn't work. This is my error, 
'hotelSys.logIn.reader' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method

Comment: Also, `ToString()` will print out the default implementation in Object. You need to cast it to a string

Comment: This is the new error when I changed my code:

'object' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4):

Some problems with your code.

First of all you should user parametrized commands to avoid possible SQL Injection attacks. Second you are moving your `reader` forward twice, so second `reader.Read()` won't return any rows assuming that your query results in 1 row returned (as it should have when we are logging in user).

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Id from tblUser where userName = @username and userPass = @pass", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUser.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPass.Text);

con.Open();

//Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Extra columns or rows are ignored.
object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

if (value == null)
{
   //login failed
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("You have successfully logged in!");

  homeMain homeMain = new homeMain();

  homeMain.Passvalue = txtUser.Text;
  homeMain.Passvalue = value.ToString();
  homeMain.Show();
  this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sure. I'll give this a try. I'm actually new to C#. :D

Answer (score 2):

First for injection reason use parameters:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select ID from tbluser where userName =@param1 and userPass =@param2", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@param1",txtUser.Text )
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2" ,txtPass.Text )
```

Secondly once you have defined to get only the ID you can set:

```
...

con.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                     
using (con)
      {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        lblID.Text=reader[0].ToString();
                    }
       }
```